# How to prevent Ruby plist converting &apos; to &#39?

Tags: ruby, xcode, plist

I'm using `plist` gem to manipulate existing plist, however, after saving I found the single quote (represented as `&apos;` being converted to `&#39`), the script is used to modify a plist used by an XCode project, which is also editable in XCode, and XCode saves single quote as `&apos;`.

So my question is: is there a way to force Ruby to use the same as XCode? I guess if not, the last resort is to add some line which manually converts all `&#39;` to `&apos;` after running the Ruby script.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plist gem uses [`CGI.escapeHTML`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI/Util.html#escapeHTML-method) which escapes special characters `'&"<>`:

```
require 'cgi'

CGI.escapeHTML("foo'bar")
#=> "foo&#39;bar"
```

If we take a look at its [implementation](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_7_1/lib/cgi/util.rb#L41-L55), we see that it's actually Ruby code. The method is basically a `gsub` call using a hash: (I'm omitting some encoding stuff)

```
module CGI::Util
  # ...

  # The set of special characters and their escaped values
  TABLE_FOR_ESCAPE_HTML__ = {
    "'" => '&#39;',
    '&' => '&amp;',
    '"' => '&quot;',
    '<' => '&lt;',
    '>' => '&gt;',
  }

  # Escape special characters in HTML, namely '&\"<>
  #   CGI.escapeHTML('Usage: foo "bar" <baz>')
  #      # => "Usage: foo &quot;bar&quot; &lt;baz&gt;"
  def escapeHTML(string)
    # ...
    string.gsub(/['&\"<>]/, TABLE_FOR_ESCAPE_HTML__)
  end

  # ...
end
```

So we can just change the constant to fit our needs, right?

```
CGI::TABLE_FOR_ESCAPE_HTML__["'"] = "&apos;"

CGI.escapeHTML("foo'bar")
#=> "foo&#39;bar" <- ???
```

Why does `escapeHTML` still return `&#39;`? It turns out that [right after the method definition](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_7_1/lib/cgi/util.rb#L57-L60), a library called `cgi/escape` is included:

```
  begin
    require 'cgi/escape'
  rescue LoadError
  end
```

And guess what - `cgi/escape` overrides `escapeHTML` by a [C implementation](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_7_1/ext/cgi/escape/escape.c) with hard-coded values for performance reasons.

---

However, not all is lost. We could try to revert the C implementation to its original form:

```
method = CGI::Util.instance_method(:escapeHTML)
unless method.owner == CGI::Util
  method = method.super_method until method.owner == CGI::Util
  CGI::define_singleton_method(:escapeHTML, method)
end

CGI::TABLE_FOR_ESCAPE_HTML__["'"] = '&apos;'
CGI.escapeHTML("foo'bar")
#=> "foo&apos;bar"
```

But that would change `CGI.escapeHTML` globally which might have undesired side effects.

A less intrusive way is to implement a `CGI` module under the `Plist` namespace with a custom `escapeHTML` method: (so only plist will use this implementation)

```
require 'plist'

module Plist
  class CGI
    TABLE_FOR_ESCAPE_HTML__ = ::CGI::TABLE_FOR_ESCAPE_HTML__.merge("'" => '&apos;')

    def self.escapeHTML(string)
      string.gsub(/['&\"<>]/, TABLE_FOR_ESCAPE_HTML__)
    end
  end
end

puts Plist::Emit.dump("foo'bar")
```

Output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<string>foo&apos;bar</string>
</plist>
```

The gem should probably avoid `CGI.escapeHTML` and provide its own escape mechanism to be Apple/XCode compliant. (you might want to open a feature request)

Comment: Thanks, let me try!